# Converting an input string to a list of sub lists with numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

I am learning Python 3. One thing I am doing to get some repetition is going through checkio. It is a website with coding exercises. One of the exercises gives an input string as follows:

```
str_to_nbrs("(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)")

str_to_nbrs("(3,7),(6,10),(9,7)")
```

I need the output of this code to produce a list of sub lists with the pairs of numbers so I can put them into variables to use for calculations.

This exercise actually has to do with x and y coordinates and circles. I am not sure why this input was in the form of a string. But, it gives me a chance to learn how to use the tools to convert a string like this to numbers that I can use in mathematical processes.

I figured out how to accomplish what I need. I am relatively new to Python 3. But, from what I have seen already, it is a well-thought-out and efficient language. I would bet there is a better way to do it with less code.

Please note that I added the big obvious comments to explain what the code is doing. They are not part of my regular coding style.

One more thing: I am still trying to come up with a convention for variable names. I have started lists with "l_". I try to give things meaningful names, but also try to keep them relatively short. I know "l_work" isn't a good name. But, I just wanted to finish that section of code, and used that...err...unimaginative name.

```
import re

# str_to_nbrs("(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)")

def str_to_nbrs(data):
    print("String input:")
    print(data)
    print()
    new_data = re.sub(r"\(","",data)
    new_data = new_data + ","

    print("Remove left parenthesis and add a comma a the end for split method:")
    print(new_data) 
    print()

    l_data = new_data.split("),")
    l_data.pop()
    print("Reformatted string data in a list:")
    print(l_data)
    print()

    l_work = []
    l_nbrs = []
    l_all = []

    for i in l_data:
        l_work = i.split(",")
        for j in l_work:
            l_nbrs.append(int(j))
        l_all.append(l_nbrs)
        l_nbrs = []
    print("Integers in sub lists:")
    print(l_all)
    print()
    print("---------------------")
    print()


str_to_nbrs("(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)")
str_to_nbrs("(3,7),(6,10),(9,7)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.sub(r"\(","",data)` is not a very good use of regular expressions. You could have more easily achieved the same result with `data.replace("(", "")`.

But since you are already using regular expressions, why not use them to do more:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+,\d+', "(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)")
['2,2', '6,2', '2,6']
```

This regular expression finds all digits (`\d`) (allows also multiple digits using `+`), which are separated only by a comma. Since different pairs also have parenthesis around them, this just gives you a list of the pairs.

By adding parenthesis around the digits, this captures each of them and splits each pair:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+),(\d+)', "(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)")
[('2', '2'), ('6', '2'), ('2', '6')]
```

Now all that is left to do is convert them to integers and put it in a function:

```
def str_to_nbrs(data):
    return [list(map(int, p)) for p in re.findall(r'(\d+),(\d+)', data)]
```

Comment: Yes - string.replace(). I was looking at the TutorialsPoint RegExp page. I should have looked at the String page. I had no idea that re.findall() existed. I need to look at the Python 3 Documentation more. I bookmarked the RegExp page at section 6.2. I am still learning where to go for reference/documentation. The official Python Documentation is so big. But, I need to learn to find things there.

Comment: @gina try https://devdocs.io/python~3.6

Answer (score 2):

The [Abstract Syntax Trees module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html) is perfect for converting string literals into python values, such as lists and tuples.  Specifically, the `ast.literal_eval()` method in [AST Helpers](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast-helpers).

```
def str_to_nbrs(data):
    return ast.literal_eval("[" + data + "]")

>>> str_to_nbrs("(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)")

[(2, 2), (6, 2), (2, 6)]
```

Surrounding the string `"(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)"` with `[` and `]` characters will turn it into the literal string for a list, which is necessary to ensure the result is a nested list of tuples.

```
ast.literal_eval("[(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)]")  # [(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)]  list of tuples
ast.literal_eval("(2,2),(6,2),(2,6)")    # ((2,2),(6,2),(2,6))  tuple of tuples
ast.literal_eval("[(2,2)]")              # [(2,2)]              list of 1 tuple
ast.literal_eval("(2,2)")                # (2,2)                Oops! Not a tuple of tuples!
```

Note: You can surround the string with with `(   )`, but `"((2,2))"` still evaluates as the tuple `(2,2)`.  You need the trailing comma `"((2,2),)"` in order to convert to the nested tuple of exactly 1 tuple: `((2,2),)`

Note: Using `ast.literal_eval()` is about **4 times slower** than Graipher's method, but it handles general python literals, including strings, and dictionaries in addition to lists of tuples.  With great power comes reduced speed.

---

### Code review comments on your implementation

(Excluding what Graipher has already mentioned)

You can use slices to get selected portions of lists.  Consider `l_data`.  After `.split()`-ing, you use `.pop()` to get rid of the last element.

```
l_data = new_data.split("),")
l_data.pop()
```

You can split the data and get rid of the last element in one statement, using the slice `[:-1]`.  The slice `:-1` translates to "all elements excluding the last one".

```
l_data = new_data.split("),")[:-1]
```

The statement `l_work = []` is unnecessary.  `l_work = i.split(",")` will overwrite the initialized list.

Initializing `l_nbrs = []` outside your loop is unnecessary, and requires that you reinitialize it at the end of the loop.  Instead, move it inside the loop, at the top:

```
for i in l_data:
    l_work = i.split(",")
    l_nbrs = []            # Initialized here
    for j in l_work:
        l_nbrs.append(int(j))
    l_all.append(l_nbrs)
```

This is referred to lately as keeping your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), in contrast to WET (Write Everything Twice) code.

List comprehension is a powerful tool.  The inner loop can be replaced with the following single statement:

```
    l_nbrs = [ int(j) for j in l_work ]
```

Once you understand that, the code can be reduced further by avoiding the single use `l_work` and `l_nbrs` variables::

```
for i in l_data:
    l_all.append( [ int(j) for j in i.split(",") ] )
```